# How to avoid the following discrepancy in my chatting app between client and server?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, sockets, python-sockets

As in my chatting app here, when client sends a message sends a message to server it becomes necessary for server to send a reply before client can send a message again. How to avoid this?

**Server program:**

```
from socket import *
import threading
host=gethostname()
port=7776
s=socket()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
print "Server is Ready!"
def client():
    c, addr= s.accept()
    while True:

        print c.recv(1024)
        c.sendto(raw_input(), addr)

for i in range(1,100):
    threading.Thread(target=client).start()
s.close()
```

**Client program:**

```
from socket import *
host=gethostname()
port=7776
s=socket()
s.connect((host, port))

while True:
    s.send(( raw_input()))
    data= s.recv(1024)
    if data:
        print data
s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you were meant to make the central server receive messages from clients, and send them to all other clients, was it not? What you implemented isn't exactly that - instead, the server process just prints all messages that arrive from the clients.

Anyways, based on the way you implemented it, here's a way to do it:

**Server:**

```
from socket import *
import threading

def clientHandler():
    c, addr = s.accept()
    c.settimeout(1.0)

    while True:
        try:
            msg = c.recv(1024)
            if msg:
                print "Message received from address %s: %s" % (addr, msg)
        except timeout:
            pass

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 7776
s = socket()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)

for i in range(1, 100):
    threading.Thread(target=clientHandler).start()
s.close()
print "Server is Ready!"
```

**Client**:

```
from socket import *

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 7776

s = socket()
s.settimeout(0.2)

s.connect((host, port))

print "Client #%x is Ready!" % id(s)

while True:
    msg = raw_input("Input message to server: ")
    s.send(msg)

    try:
        print s.recv(1024)
    except timeout:
        pass

s.close()
```

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. Last version was just an "inspiration" I thought you could use, now I actually ran it. Let me know if it answers your question and now you know how to proceed.

Comment: Thank you. One last doubt. How do I open a port on my public ip address so that computers outside my system too can connect to it?

Comment: You'd need to connect to your router Admin Control Panel and open a TCP port, and forward it to your own computer. Be careful though, you definitely don't want to expose your machine to the internet if you can avoid it, save for specific ports. Never do DMZ forwarding, and never disable the firewall. An option to automatically control your router to open a TCP port might be this: https://github.com/skatkov/upnp-client-lib - have a look. Also, feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem. :)